# Prime Number Inequality unclear

Tags: elementary-number-theory

\

If $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number prove that $p_{n+1}^2<p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ when $n>=4$

Thaks,
Payam

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $121 = 11^2 < 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 210$

Suppose the statement is true for some positive integer $k \ge 4$. Then

$p_1p_2\cdots p_{k+1} = \left(p_1p_2\cdots p_k\right)p_{k+1} > p_{k+1}^2p_{k+1} = p_{k+1}^3$ (by the induction assumption).

So, you want to show that $p_{k+2}^2 < p_{k+1}^3$.